# Use of function pointers in C on data structure development

Tags: c, data-structures, function-pointers

I'm having an Algorithms course next semester and so I dived into C with the purpose of making a few data structures ahead of time to be prepared.

As I learned about function pointers, I found I could store them in `structs` and create an object-oriented-like use for my data structure. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void insert(char * object)
{
    printf("Adding %s to the data structure\n", object);
}


typedef struct data_structure {
    char * obj;
    void (*insert)(char * object);
} data_structure;


int main()
{
    data_structure d;
    d.insert = insert;

    d.insert("bacon");

    return 0;
}
```

But is this kind of procedure actually useful in the scope of data structure and algorithm studying in C? Or is it just taking up memory on the data structure?

I've found other posts talking about function pointers, but none that explores this kind of approach. I think this could be useful to a bunch of curious students out there :)

Comment: Google for something like "generic linked list in C". When I was studying it it was known under the name "ADT" (Abstract Data Type), but apparently it is really hard to find it by this term, so I assume it is not commonly used for this purpose.

Comment: This is an anti pattern, it nets you nothing but slower and bad code.

Comment: I've done my fair bit of googling "generic *insert any major data structure*". I don't see how that relates to my question, though

Comment: First result: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-linked-list-in-c-2/ - using functon pointers. Perhaps not in structure, but you can easily modify it.

Comment: @Fredrik Is it? Fact or opinion?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know how to use them for this purpose, my question is about the effectiveness and advantages of doing so. Thank you for the reply though!

Comment: @Fredrik would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Saucy well for starters, insert can’t insert anything as it doesn’t have access to the data structure, which means you have you have to pass it as an argument. Which in turn means you could have skipped the function pointer to begin with. Just write a function and call it.

Comment: If you wish to have encapsulation and write OO code in C, this is actually the correct way to do it.  You do have to pass d to the insert function though, as a "this" to allow it to manipulate the data. 

C++ is essentially doing the same thing under the covers to have classes with methods that operate on 'this' which is essentially a hidden parameter to each method.  Data hiding can also be achieved by putting all 'private' data into another internal struct and have a void * in the parent struct to that data.

Comment: Thank you to everyone that replied. I'll try to make an answer and edit it according to any further comments and improvements. Cheers

Comment: @Saucy secondly, say you did all that anyways and kept the function pointer, what did you win? Nothing really, function pointers can be NULL so you have to protect against that. Your structures are bigger. The code gets slower as you get more lookups.

Comment: Saucy, generally you also need a constructor like routine that is NOT part of the structure to init all you function pointers and any relevant private data.  As as one who has written a little code this way and a lot of code not, and having profiled it on real systems, this doesn't really add any meaningful overhead in my experience.

Comment: If you're only going to use one function in the function pointer, you probably don't gain much.  If you're going to set the function pointer so it points to different functions at different times, you may gain from having the pointer in the structure.  Use it when you need it, not by default (unless you find yourself needing it by default, for your coding style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all the answers, here's the insight this post gathered regarding the use of function pointers as C structure attributes.

Advantages:

- Good ol' practise on a somewhat advanced subject if you're a student
- Provides encapsulation and object oriented code in C
- Gives you better understanding of the object orientated programming paradigm if you're not already well familiarized with it
- Can be used to implement VTables

Disadvantages:

- On a functional level, you still have to pass the data structure to the function, as it doesn't have access to said data structure
- Slight performance overhead

In conclusion, the use of function pointers as in the original question would really only have practical uses if one wishes to explore OOP whilst getting into more advanced aspects of C, or to construct VTables.

Thank you to all the people who replied.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have certainly seen objects constructed this way as sets of function pointers effectively representing a vtable. Usually, for a vtable you add one extra level of indirection such that all data objects with similar traits point to the same function pointer object. This reduces the cost per data object if there is more than 1 function, but at a slight execution cost.

It can also be used as a lightweight way to organise and structure function+voiddata callback objects, by insisting that the first member of the data is the callback function. Of course, you can't define inherited classes using c, but you can have nested structures which can be bullied to the same purpose.